# ubuntu 16.04 only reading audio files on microsoft windows cd's

Tags: sound

my old hd with ubuntu 14.04 reads all made for windows disc ubuntu 16.04 only reads the audio files only from the same disc,i have tried all fixes and nothing works,,i have tried for years to switch over to linux and there is always one small bug in the system that stops me every time the best i ever used was ubuntu 10 every thing since has been a nightmare each new ubuntu has a new major problem,looks like i may have to give up on linux just something with every new release,i really want to switch but i have fooled with linux a long time and its just constant problems same thing happens with zorin os 11 im gonig back to my old ubuntu 14.o4 hd cause it reads windows disc audio and exe files please tell me there is an upgrade coming for ubuntu 16.04 and zorin os that will fix this.im about to abandon ship.

Comment: What are the files you're trying to access? If it's Windows software, then it will not work under Linux easily (just like Linux software does not work on Windows easily). (Some, but not all, software does work under WINE, but this can be a bit hit-or-miss.) The point is, Linux is not Windows, and if you expect it to run all your Windows software, you're better off just using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I finally wiped the hard disk and fresh-installed.

I then added PlayOnLinux as before (`sudo apt install playonlinux`)

Finally, DVD support:

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Now everything works!